# If test - checking files older than 7 days - Unix

Tags: linux, unix, linux-kernel, synology

I have created a script for my Synology NAS which checks the video folder to see if there are files older than seven days. However it is not deleting, the error message I am getting is

```
sh: of: unknown operand
```

Here is my script:

```
echo "------- SCRIPT START -------"
sleep 2

if test 'find /volume1/Media/ -mtime +7'
        then
                sleep 2
                echo "Deleting files"
                -exec rm -r {} \;
                sleep 2
                echo "Deleted files"
        else
                echo "There are no files to delete"
fi
```

Comment: How do you start your script exactly?

Comment: It's called 'media.sh', so I start it ./media.sh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a short script to just remove files older than 7 days:

```
dir="/volume1/Media"
days=7
echo -n "removing files in $dir that are older than $days days: "
find "$dir" -mtime +$days -type f -exec echo {} \; -exec rm {} \; | wc -l
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your code into

```
find /volume1/Media/ -mtime +7 -type f -exec echo rm -f {} \;
```

The echo is for testing, remove it when you like the resulting rm commands.

When you also want to remove the directories, you can change it into

```
find /volume1/Media/ -mtime +7 -exec echo rm -rf {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

You definitely don't need to -exec and the {} is substituting what exactly and you don't need ; and you should probably cd to the directory where you actually want to remove the files because otherwise it looks like you are going to check whether or not there is a file and then delete everthing in the pwd.  That might not be ideal, depending on where this script is running.

So just put a test file in that folder and do this, then change the rm -r * to delete just the one file(s) you want to delete depending on what you are actually trying to do.

```
echo "------- SCRIPT START -------"
sleep 2

echo "Checking Game of Thrones"
sleep 2
if test 'find /volume1/Media/ -mtime +7'
    then
            sleep 2
            echo "Deleting files"
            cd /volume1/Media
            rm -r *
            sleep 2
            echo "Deleted files"
            cd
    else
            echo "There are no files to delete"
fi
```

Comment: Well don't delete everything by using *...  just add another if in there that removes only the old files!  :)

Comment: I want to delete everything

Comment: careful: `'find /volume...'` is a non-empty string and no command to be executed. Hence, it's always true and you always remove everything in `/volume1/Media` when running this script!

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that. How do I fix this?